# How to include path from ignored node_modules in flow config

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have flow config for ignoring all folders inside 'node_modules'

But I want to Include one folder, how can I do this using flow config?

Seems that my config doesn't work and folder `date-fns` is still ignored.

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*

[include]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/date-fns/
```

Comment: q: why do you want to ignore all node_modules inside of your flowconfig? Have you seen https://medium.com/shopback-engineering/5-things-you-might-be-interested-in-your-flow-config-1ad35b023e93?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to ignore all of node_modules because it was slowing down the parsing considerably except for a few packages but I couldn't get the include to work as I expected.

For me I wanted a scoped dir to be parsed so I wrote an ocaml regex in the ignore section.

This will ignore everything in node_modules except for anything not starting with alpha characters like `@`

```
[ignore]
.*node_modules/[a-z].*
```

This might help if you wanna write your own regex
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html